# Rounding corners of UIModalPresentationFormSheet

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, rounded-corners, uimodalpresentationstyle

forgive me if this is an obvious question i am relatively new.

I have a modal view which i set up with a custom size and rounded corners:

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews{

    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];
    self.view.superview.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 600, 450);
    self.view.layer.cornerRadius  = 60.0;  
}
```

However i find that when i round the view corners, i get this greyish colour appear on the edges of it (as if theres something else behind it) : (see picture).

[image]

How do i remove these greyish edges so it shows the background content like normal? I've tried adding

```
self.view.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

however this still gives the same effect as above.

Thanks,

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];
    self.view.superview.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 600, 450);
    self.view.superview.layer.cornerRadius  = 60.0;   
    self.view.superview.layer.masksToBounds = YES;  
}
```

I think you should set corner radius of the superView.

Comment: For iOS8, try: self.view.layer instead.

Comment: That did it for me. Trick is setting this stuff in "viewWillLayoutSubviews"

Answer (score 1):

use like this

```
 - (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
 {

  [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];
  self.view.superview.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 600, 450);
  self.view.layer.cornerRadius  = 60.0;   
  self.view.layer.masksToBounds = YES; //add this line 

 }
```

Comment: Hi, Unfortunately this doesn't appear to work and the same result is shown above.

Answer (score 1):

Use this, it will remove the shadow

```
self.view.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

Comment: Hi, Unfortunately this doesn't appear to work and the same result is shown above.

Comment: Ya, I too answered the same time when shan answered, few seconds different. I didnt noticed him

Answer (score 1):

It turns out you need to round the superview and mask the superview;

```
[self.view superview].layer.cornerRadius = 30.0f;
[self.view superview].layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

So in the end its looked like this :)

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews{
    //setup custom size modal view
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];
    self.view.superview.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 600, 450);
    [self.view superview].layer.cornerRadius = 30.0f;
    [self.view superview].layer.masksToBounds = YES;
}
```

Thanks for your help Shan